# Managing opensource licenses using Maven

Tags: maven, open-source

It is typical for any project to use multiple open source JARs. My question is, what is the best practice for organising all of the license files in your deployment using maven?

For instance, are the licenses suppose to be consolidated into one uber-license file / mentioned separately in the headers for every file / contained in a separate license per jar etc.

I am a newbie when it comes to open source licenses and how I should use them. Would appreciate some help and guidance in this area.

Thanks.

Comment: Which licenses do you have in mind if you are talking about open source? Apache, GPL, LGPL ?

Comment: yup.. i'm talking about all open source licences like the ones you stated.

Answer (score 1):

It is typical for project to use several different jar which usually have some kind of open source license. But this depends on the project. Furthermore the ordering etc. of the licenses which are used in the project depends of the requirement of the appropriate licenses. Some of the licenses require to be mentioned in the project itself other allow the usage in commercial projects as well.

Which solution you have to follow depends on the licenses. Either a single file which contains all different licenses. This can be achieved by using the [license-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/license-maven-plugin/).

Comment: is this maven plugin intelligent enough to know all these and perform the actions accordingly? or must these rules be manually specified?